# Spark AR text integration issue while publishing

Tags: facebook, instagram, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to add shade name as text in rectangle to my Spark AR filter for Instagram. But when I try to publish the filter, I am getting The effect contains text that's not integrated into the scene of the effect" this error. Any leads would be appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK0kO.png)

Comment: Please, share your codes with us.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the issue and resolved it. According to sparkAR policy 4.3.a, We can have only one logo in the area. So I placed the shade names inside the scene. There is a slight movement for the same but still fine. Effect got published.

Thanks